# How can I use fdisk to create a ntfs partition on /dev/sdx?

Tags: partition, fdisk

I would like to know how to create a ntfs partition on /dev/sdx. I could not figure out if I should use partition type 7 86 or 87.

What is the full list of commands to use?

Comment: With `partition type 7 86 or 87` I assume you mean the `fdisk` shell partition types, of course.

Comment: This is no longer valid for GPT.... type 7 in GPT partitioning is for power pc

Comment: Yes, it seems to not work in GPT; but what is OK for GPT? 11 (Microsoft basic data)? Or 17 (HP-UX). Or is it better to change partition table to DOS for that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

1. create a partition using `fdisk`

   ```
   fdisk /dev/sdx
   ```

   Commands:

   - to create the partition: n, p, [enter], [enter]
   - to give a type to the partition: t, 7 (don't select 86 or 87, those are for volume sets)
   - if you want to make it bootable: a
   - to see the changes: p
   - to write the changes: w
2. create a ntfs fileystem on /dev/sdx1:

   ```
   mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdx1
   ```

   (the `-f` argument makes the command run fast, skipping both the bad block check and the zeroing of the storage)
3. mount it wherever you want

   ```
   mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt/myNtfsDevice
   ```

Comment: when your disk size larger than 2TB, should use gdisk instead of fdisk. commands are simliar

Comment: If your are using a GPT partition table, use 11 ([Microsoft Basic Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition)) for the type instead of 7

Comment: well explained, helped me with my 8GB usb pendrive

Comment: In gdisk 1.0.8 (at least) the type to use for Microsoft Basic Data is actually 700, as shown in the "L" output.

Comment: @temple why gdisk instead of fdisk?

Comment: The classical fdisk is only for MBR partition tables, not for GPT.

The gdisk is the equivalent of it for GPT. It is also known (from the man page) as the GPT fdisk .

Answer (score 3):

You can use **fdisk** to create the partition "*disk*" division but for the partition's file system you can use the **mkfs.ntfs** to create the file system in the partition that will use ...